# How do I add tomcat to brew services?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew

I have installed tomcat from brew. It works fine but whenever I need to start or stop tomcat I need to go to the tomcat folder with catalina and start and stop it from there. I know I could simply do this with "brew services start tomcat" but I get:

```
Error: Formula `tomcat` has not implemented #plist or installed a locatable .plist file
```

brew services list gives:

```
Warning: No services available to control with `brew services`
```

**My question is:** How do I add tomcat to brew services?

Comment: You have to `brew edit tomcat` and modify the formula. If you succeed please do a pull request.

Comment: There is already a trial here : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/12249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tomcat` formula is now able to start and stop Tomcat with:

```
brew services start tomcat
```

and

```
brew services stop tomcat
```

Thanks to Maxime Faye and [this commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/5faab57f3f61d4fc51e128db801195a437ccdcf2).

Run:

```
brew upgrade
```

to obtain this new feature.

### Old answer

Here is the modified formula coming from the [closed pull request mentioned in the comments](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/12249). You can `brew edit tomcat`, replace the whole content and then `brew upgrade tomcat`. I've tested it and it works well. Hopefully, it will be soon merged in the master branch.

```
class Tomcat < Formula
  desc "Implementation of Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages"
  homepage "https://tomcat.apache.org/"
  revision 1

  stable do
    url "https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.16/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.16.tar.gz"
    mirror "https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.16/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.16.tar.gz"
    sha256 "939fb7c9fae3298dd0ccb4724b9c943c524e8af287531c8f3bbec0707e5780f1"

    depends_on :java => "1.7+"

    resource "fulldocs" do
      url "https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.16/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.16-fulldocs.tar.gz"
      mirror "https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.16/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.16-fulldocs.tar.gz"
      sha256 "89fb481635834af7abc9cfefd67b530f1f3154c3bc2a820ceeb80e2e9c0d91c0"
    end
  end

  devel do
    url "https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M22/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22.tar.gz"
    mirror "https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M22/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22.tar.gz"
    version "9.0.0.M22"
    sha256 "c1b359d52edae793dde83cb65ef47dc202e8394d7328c823a9a53c02d09f2742"

    depends_on :java => "1.8+"

    resource "fulldocs" do
      url "https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M22/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22-fulldocs.tar.gz"
      mirror "https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M22/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22-fulldocs.tar.gz"
      version "9.0.0.M22"
      sha256 "57223a9dd8d1b164a492432f04fbcf02a390777e2aaa252b5574d5ed607acc60"
    end
  end

  bottle :unneeded

  option "with-fulldocs", "Install full documentation locally"

  def install
    # Remove Windows scripts
    rm_rf Dir["bin/*.bat"]

    # Install files
    prefix.install %w[NOTICE LICENSE RELEASE-NOTES RUNNING.txt]
    libexec.install Dir["*"]
    bin.install_symlink "#{libexec}/bin/catalina.sh" => "catalina"

    (share/"fulldocs").install resource("fulldocs") if build.with? "fulldocs"
  end

  plist_options :manual => "catalina run"

  def plist; <<-EOS.undent
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>#{plist_name}</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>#{opt_bin}/catalina</string>
          <string>run</string>
        </array>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
    </plist>
    EOS
  end

  test do
    ENV["CATALINA_BASE"] = testpath
    cp_r Dir["#{libexec}/*"], testpath
    rm Dir["#{libexec}/logs/*"]

    pid = fork do
      exec bin/"catalina", "start"
    end
    sleep 3
    begin
      system bin/"catalina", "stop"
    ensure
      Process.wait pid
    end
    File.exist? testpath/"logs/catalina.out"
  end
end
```